# I think the clipboard empty itself in this code. What can I do?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I'm trying to copy cells from file A, sheet 1 to file B, sheet 1. File A is already created and I'm creating file B in my code :

```
Sub Save()
    Dim directory, fileName As String
    Dim nbLigneImportCanope As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '' Path
    directory = "\\path\"

    '' Number of line in file A
    nbLigneImportCanope = 1
        While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Kibana").Range("A" & nbLigneImportCanope).Value <> ""
            nbLigneImportCanope = nbLigneImportCanope + 1
        Wend
    nbLigneImportCanope = nbLigneImportCanope - 1

    '' Copy from file A
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Kibana").Range("A1" & ":V" & nbLigneImportCanope).Copy

    '' Creation of file B
    fileName = InputBox("Entrer le nom du fichier :", "Création d'un nouveau fichier...", "KIBANA_01022019")

    If fileName <> "" Then
        Set NewWkbk = Workbooks.Add
        NewWkbk.SaveAs directory & "\" & fileName
    End If

    '' Paste in file B
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

But I end up with an

> error 1004 - paste method worksheet class failed.

I checked and realized before this bit of code :

```
'' Creation of file B
fileName = InputBox("Entrer le nom du fichier :", "Création d'un nouveau fichier...", "KIBANA_01022019")
```

The clipboard was ok, with the right data I want to paste, and right after it, it was empty.

Any of you have an idea?

Comment: Copy  only after you have added the new workbook. Once you add/open a workbook excel drops the copy. same happens with when you add a new sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer !

But how can I avoid switching from one workbook to another every time I need to do something on each one of them ?

Comment: Isn't it ? So I can't avoid the switches ... Feels bad. I'll try something else and let you know, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

As cyboashu wrote in his comment, you should copy only after opening the new workbook. Plus, it is possible to give the destination range as parameter to the `Copy` command.

Additionally, in your code you are missing the `else`-branch for `If fileName <> ""`, so when no filename is selected, you would paste the data to whatever sheet is active at that moment.

Your code could look like

```
'' Creation of file B
fileName = InputBox("Entrer le nom du fichier :", "Création d'un nouveau fichier...", "KIBANA_01022019")

If fileName <> "" Then
    Set NewWkbk = Workbooks.Add
    NewWkbk.SaveAs directory & "\" & fileName
else 
    exit sub ' (or whatever you want to do)
End If

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Kibana").Range("A1" & ":V" & nbLigneImportCanope).Copy _
    NewWkbk.WorkSheets(1).Range("A1")
```